# Should there be a definite article here?

Tags: definite-articles

In the following, should there be a "the" in front of "standard of living"?

> Assess the extent to which the improvement of standard of living in Japan is dependent on the openness of the economy.

Comment: Assess the extent to which an improvement in the standard of living in Japan is dependent on the openness of the economy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the definite article '*the*', 'standard of living' refers to a generalised use, not related to a particular country/economic bracket etc.

eg With the global rise in the number of retirees, *standard of living* is seen as a major area of concern for many governments.

Using the phrase to refer to a particular country requires the definite article '*the*' for its standard closed specifier function.

In the interest of completeness may I suggest two further changes that may well enhance the grammar:
(i) deletion of '*the*' before 'improvement'. This is a common construction that leaves open the possibility that there will be a plurality of such improvements;
(ii) modifying 'improvement of' to 'improvement *in*'. This collocation is far more widely used.
eg Improvement in healthcare, improvement in the taste of produce, ... (examples abound)

My suggested amended topic heading thus reads:
**Assess the extent to which improvement in the standard of living in Japan is dependent on the openness of the economy.**
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=improvement%20of%20the%20standard%20of%2Cimprovement%20in%20the%20standard%20of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimprovement%20of%20the%20standard%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimprovement%20in%20the%20standard%20of%3B%2Cc0) shows, ***in*** is far more likely than ***of***...

[image]

...and as [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=improvement%20of%20the%20standard%20of%2Cimprovement%20in%20the%20standard%20of%2Cimprovement%20of%20standard%20of%20living%2Cimprovement%20in%20standard%20of%20living&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimprovement%20of%20the%20standard%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimprovement%20in%20the%20standard%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimprovement%20of%20standard%20of%20living%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimprovement%20in%20standard%20of%20living%3B%2Cc0) shows, we usually *do* include the article in OP's context...

[image]

But it's really just a stylistic choice, not a matter of right/wrong. Having said that, I think if there are *too many* of these "potentially optional" articles the text becomes unnaturally "wordy". So I'd remove the earlier one...

> *...the extent to which <strike>the</strike> improvement **in the** standard of living in Japan is [blah blah]*

(But then again, I might pluralize ***improvements*** anyway. It's all subjective.)

Comment: So you'd say my sentence is technically correct, but perhaps could be improved stylistically?

Comment: Absolutely. You can't do NGram charts for strings of more than 5 words. Google Books allows any length search strings, but it wildly overestimates expected results for strings that happen to include lots of common "glue" words like ***the** improvement **in the** standard **of** living*. If you search for that string and scroll through the results, there are actually only 25. But if you do the same without the second article, you'll find a total of 26 hits. That's because writers don't like the stylistically clumsy repetition, not because of some grammatical rule or fine semantic distinction.